# theme.res getting corrupted when i rebuild the project which used to work using JDK 8

Tags: codenameone

I see theme.res being corrupted continuously and threme.res replaced with corrupted version in the project. Following is the message from console. Please let me know what can be done on this -

```
Exception while reading font from resource path /com/codename1/impl/javase/Roboto-Thin.ttf
java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.createFont0(Font.java:1183)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:1052)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.loadTrueTypeFont(JavaSEPort.java:7010)
    at com.codename1.ui.Font.createTrueTypeFont(Font.java:212)
    at com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager.resetThemeProps(UIManager.java:412)
    at com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager.<init>(UIManager.java:108)
    at com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager.getInstance(UIManager.java:126)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:1098)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.loadTrueTypeFont(JavaSEPort.java:7059)
    at com.codename1.ui.Font.createTrueTypeFont(Font.java:212)
    at com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager.resetThemeProps(UIManager.java:412)
    at com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager.<init>(UIManager.java:108)
    at com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager.getInstance(UIManager.java:126)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:1098)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.createFont0(Font.java:1183)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:1052)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.loadTrueTypeFont(JavaSEPort.java:7010)
    ... 7 more
Compile is forcing compliance to the supported API's/features for maximum device compatibility. This allows smaller
        code size and wider device support
```

Answer (score 0):

I just verified that the file is there and hasn't been changed for a long while.

Which JDK are you using on which OS?

Notice that Codename One supports JDK 8 and JDK 11. If you're using a headless environment or an odd JDK distribution I suggest moving to a standard JDK environment.

Comment: I'm using JDK 11. This conflict error is consistently showing when i re-build the project.  Do you see if there is anything causing this issues.

Comment: Which JDK vendor? Under which OS? Are you running headless? What command are you using to trigger this?